# Equivalence of being radical for homogeneous ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals

**Proposition.** Let $I \subset k[x_0,\dots, x_r]$ be a homogeneous ideal. Then $I$ is radical if and only if $\forall f \in k[x_0,\dots, x_r]$ homogeneous such than $f^n \in I$ for some $n \geq 1$ implies $f \in I$.

**Proof.** First implication is trivial. Reciprocally, by reductio ad absurdum suppose $\exists f$ such than $f^n \in I$ for some $n\geq 1$ but $f\notin I$. We can write $f = \sum_{i=1}^{\deg{f}} f_i$ where $f_i$ is the $i$th homogeneous component of $f$.

Since $f \notin I$, then $\exists f_j$ such than $f_j\notin I$. We define $e=\max{\{i\mid f_i \notin I\}}$. Let consider the $ne$-grade homogeneous component of $f^n$ 
$$
(f^n)_{n\cdot e} = \underset{i_1+\dotsc+i_n=ne}{\sum_{i_1,\dotsc,i_n =1}^d} f_{i_1}\cdots f_{i_n}.
$$
If $i>e$ then $f_i \in I$. In every adden (except $f_e^n$) there exists $i_j >e$. Therefore every adden is in $I$ excepting, a priori, $f_e^n$. Since $f^n \in I$, all homogenous component of $f^n$ are in $I$, so $(f^n)_{n\cdot e}\in I$ and $f_e^n \in I$. By hypothesis, it implies $f_e\in I$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Do you try to ask something?

Comment: @user26857 Someone who check my proof

Comment: Excepting the "word" *adden* everything sounds right.

Comment: I agree, it is fine, except that with "adden" you probably mean "addend". I would say "summand" or maybe even "term", but it doesn't matter.

Comment: @ZachTeitler Thank you very much